# Rectangular Pulse Train and Sinc Function

Tags: fourier-series, time-domain, sinc, pulse

I wanted to ask that in frequency domain the rectangular pulse is a sinc function, so is this sinc function periodic or aperiodic?

Also if signals that are continuous in time domain then they are aperiodic in frequency domain?

Comment: hi! So, what have your considerations been so far? For your first question, that can literally be answered by looking at a plot of the sinc. Or at the formula. And applying the definition of "periodic". So, that should be pretty possible for someone who knows what "periodic" means! Where's the point in that, specifically, that you need help with?

Comment: You need to clarify - the title refers to a rectangular pulse train, while the body of the question refers to rectangular pulse - these are two different things.